# Integrate a MS Word Editor

Tags: user-interface, ms-word, web, editor

I'm currently creating a web site, in which I want to integrate a Microsoft Office Word editor. I'm not searching a javascript lib like 'https://poi.apache.org/' but a UI editor.

Is there anything available on the Microsoft API's page or should I find it somewhere else ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use TinyMce WYSIWYG editor for your website. Here Is the [demo](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/full-featured/):

It's like word editor, but if you can't use java files in your website, you can use it as CDN .. here is the [tinymce cdn library](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/tinymce)

Comment: Thanks ULTRAMAX for your answer, I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using CKEditor since there's a free open source version of it.
[CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/)

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at this links.